# Adjective made out of swim meaning swimmable

Tags: vocabulary, slang

I know this question does not make sense, but if I wanted to construct a word meaning swimmable (i.e. be able to swim inside more accurately) in a parallel way to lets say smell->smelly, how would I do that?

I list the three options that came to my mind:

1. swimmy
2. swimmie
3. swimmey

Thanks

**P.S: I know that a word like that probably does not exist: this is why I am asking "if I wanted to construct..."**

Comment: If such a word exists or has been ever coined by some author, I don't have the slightest idea. But , for the sake of completeness- Do you mean a liquid with ideal viscosity/buoyancy etc in which someone can swim, or A water body which is safe/healthy/clear enough to be swimmer-friendly ?

Comment: Hello, schris. The suggestion of D-I-Y candidates (for words) is expressly off-topic on ELU. As the comment above illustrates, 'nonce words' would rarely have a totally obvious meaning. ELU looks at established usage. There _are_ rules of thumb showing how adjectives and corresponding verbs are related in form, but these do not guarantee that all such pairs exist in the lexis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I suspect that the asker is unaware that [the adjective *swimmy* **already exists**](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195856) with various established senses none of which have anything to do with [natatorial activities](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125266). :)

Comment: Do you mean capable of being swum **in**, or do you mean capable of being swum **across**? A body of water's natability does not normally refer to whether it is intransnatable.

Comment: Can you supply a sentence by way of example with a blank space for the required word?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off with: **able**. This is not foreseeable, doable, imaginable, for example.  *This river is not swimmable*.

English likes made up words that work (No, I did not check the OED or some other dictionary). See this article:

> Efforts to make the Charles **swimmable** date at least to the passage of
> the Clean Water Act of 1972. In the 1980s, the Metropolitan District
> Commission installed six pumps designed to push oxygen into layers of
> decay on the river bottom. In 1995, the Environmental Protection
> Agency began the Clean Charles River Initiative, aimed at making the
> river swimmable and fishable by 2005.

[Boston Globe](http://archive.boston.com/bostonglobe/editorial_opinion/oped/articles/2010/05/15/a_river_thats_fit_for_swimming/)

Comment: OP wants some sort of hyponym of 'swimmable'.

Comment: OP mentions 'swimmable'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, **the** OP says  a word meaning swimmable. How about that is the word and there is most likely not another.

Answer (score 0):

There is an entry for the word ***swimmable*** in the Oxford English Dictionary, with examples dating from 1852 - though the 1966 one is of a slighly different sense and spelling. Does the following help?

> Capable of being swum; (also swimmable-in) suitable for swimming in.
>
> 1852   M. W. Savage Reuben Medlicott iv. iv   I rode everything
> rideable,..swam everything swimmable.
>
> 1866   Reader 10 Feb. 145/1   Within swimmable distance of the shore.
>
> 1963   P. McCutchan Man from Moscow ix. 91   The sea's swimmable-in,
> if you're a Spartan.
>
> 1966   Telegraph (Brisbane) 3 Feb. 18 (caption)    Bare midriff
> camisole tops are the latest on the patio this summer. Worn with snug
> hip-hugger jams in nylon knit. Both are completely swimable.
>
> 1976   National Observer (U.S.) 13 Mar. 7/2   Congress poured money
> into it to help cities do their part in achieving ‘swimmable,
> fishable’ waters.

Comment: Although this _does_ have references for both the usual senses, OP does ask for a different word. And one doesn't need to use OED to find both 'that can be swum across' and 'that can be swum in' definitions of 'swimmable', so this is general reference as far as the use of this word goes.

Comment: So, you don't get a downvote but I do even though I had a newspaper reference? People around here are so mean.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It might help if he'd produce a sentence with a blank space. I am actually a little confused about what he does want.